# How much of the manga does the Death Note musical cover?

Tags: death-note

How much of the *DEATH NOTE* manga does the Frank Wildhorn [theatrical musical](http://deathnotethemusical.com/eng/) cover? (More info in English is [here](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2015-02-01/hear-death-note-the-musical-song-sung-in-english-by-tony-nominees/.83964).)

(I gather that [the Korean production](http://www.allkpop.com/article/2015/04/death-note-musical-starring-jyjs-junsu-reveals-trailer) is a translation of the same script rather than content different from the Japanese production, but if it differs, I'd like to know what part of the manga the Japanese staging covers as well as what part of the manga the Korean version covers.)

Comment: After doing a quick google search, it looks like [the English and Japanese musical adaptations center on the initial episodes in the series.](http://www.playbill.com/news/article/frank-wildhorn-musical-death-note-has-nyc-reading-with-andy-kelso-robert-cu-217333).